# Subclass Constructor isnt recognized

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

I'm trying to construct a subclass and I get error that the constructor is undefined?!?!

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LinearAlgebra
{
 public class Matrix
  {
    public int m;
    public int n;
    public float Matrix[][];
    void Matrix(int tempm, int tempn)
    {
      m = tempm;
      n = tempn;
      Matrix = new float[m-1][n-1];
    }

  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    LinearAlgebra Geometry = new LinearAlgebra();
    LinearAlgebra.Matrix Rotation = Geometry.new Matrix(3,3);

    System.out.println("hello");
  }

}
```

Sorry have been out of java for a while. I looked at some java tutorials and think I'm doing the same but it is not working
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Matrix(int tempm, int tempn)
```

This is a method not a constructor. You must remove the return type `void`:

```
Matrix(int tempm, int tempn)
```

You should also name your local variables to start with a lowercase, `geometry` instead of `Geometry`. Using an uppercase confuses the reader because it makes it seem as if the nested class `Matrix` is a static class, not an inner class. Same for the `Rotation` variable.

Comment: okay it compiles, thanks. So constructors do not need a return type? Or rather can not have one?

Comment: @marshalcraft It must not have one. Otherwise it's a method not a constructor.

Comment: yeah there are other problems as well, like I made Matrix[][] float, not sure if that is doing some kind of recursive method so I renamed it to elements[][]